# Using Atlassian Bamboo for CI for .Net projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, bamboo

Can anyone point me at a good resource on getting Bamboo to work for .Net projects (Bamboo 3, VS2010)? Despite its size, Atlassian's own help files are not all that useful, they almost totally lack both details and actual examples, especially for .Net. I can find people with similar issues on the forums, but rarely any answers.

I am not, at this point, wanting to do anything supertricky, just things like:

Setting other parameters than just Run Config (useless on vs2010) and Container on running MSTest.exe.

Passing the correct paths to custom commands/scripts (e.g. if I wanted to run MSTest that way and pass in the local.testsettings, the resultsfile etc.)

It was mildly painful getting the server set up, but this lot just seems wilfully harder than it need be!

Comment: Actually, having had a conversation with one of the guys at Atlassian, version 3.5 (due out May 10) has many improvements, so I'll save my major effort for after I see what it can do.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easiest to use the 'Script' builder type and write a batch file to do all the work of calling msbuild etc.

I've also found the [pre/post build plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/5581) to be useful, though haven't yet been able to get it working properly for running nunit-console unit tests.

I've been setting up a bamboo deployment over the past fortnight. I must admit, I've not enjoyed the experience very much at all. So far I've found Bamboo to be a bit of a disappointment compared to the other attlassian products such as JIRA which are, in my opinion, excellent.

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me! We got Bamboo because we have JIRA/Greenhopper/Confluence. As I understand, all CI products are a pain especially TFS! I've not had to do with the setup of CC or TFS, just used it when it was already going... I'm not at all script-happy, and (after a previous experience) really don't like editing MSBuild AT ALL. Bamboo 3.5 is out May 10th and has many improvements. Still, it's a little sad to see that the state-of-the-art in CI is not even up to the systems I (and my colleagues) wrote for ourselves 10 years ago.